# How can I delete marker from google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Please help me to delete marker from the map after click on it.

I wrote a script. The marker is created after mouse left button click on the map. The marker should be deleted after mouse right button click on the marker.

However, it works only for one marker. For 2, 3 or 4 markers the script is not working. Please help me to fix the issue.

js:

```
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044}
  });

  renderMarkers();

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    var lat = e.latLng.lat();
    var lng = e.latLng.lng();    
    var id = 'id_' + Date.now() + lat.toFixed(2) + lng.toFixed(2);
    generateMarker(lat, lng, id);    
  });  
}

function getMarkersFromLocalStorage() {
  return localStorage.markers ? JSON.parse(localStorage.markers) : {};
};

function addMarkerToLocalStorage(lat, lng, id) {
  var markers = getMarkersFromLocalStorage();
  markers[id] = {
    lat: lat, 
    lng: lng
  };
  localStorage.markers = JSON.stringify(markers);
};

function removeMarkerFromLocalStorage(id) {
  console.log('removeMarkerFromLocalStorage');
  var markers = getMarkersFromLocalStorage();
  delete markers[id];
  localStorage.markers = JSON.stringify(markers);
};

function renderMarkers() {
  var markers = getMarkersFromLocalStorage();  

  for(prop in markers) {
    generateMarker(markers[prop].lat, markers[prop].lng);
  };
};

function generateMarker(lat, lng, id) {  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
    map: map,
    id: id
  }); 
  addMarkerToLocalStorage(lat, lng, id);

  marker.addListener('rightclick', function(e) {
    var m = marker;
    console.log(e, m['id']);    
    removeMarkerFromLocalStorage(m['id']);
    this.setMap(null);
    renderMarkers(); 
  });   

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several issues in your code:

1. It's not clear why you call `renderMarkers();` in the right-click handler of the marker. This way you will re-add new markers on the map without deleting the previous ones.
2. In `renderMarkers()` function when you generate markers you are missing the third parameter in `generateMarker()` function that leads to missing id's on the markers and you have `undefined` value for `m['id']` in right-click handler.
3. The id property is not present in the [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerOptions) object specification. I believe it is safer to assign id after create marker instance like `marker.id = id;`

I've modified your example and it seems to work properly. Please have a look at modified code.

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044}
  });

  renderMarkers();

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    var lat = e.latLng.lat();
    var lng = e.latLng.lng();    
    var id = 'id_' + Date.now() + lat.toFixed(2) + lng.toFixed(2);
    generateMarker(lat, lng, id);    
  });  
}

function getMarkersFromLocalStorage() {
  return localStorage.markers ? JSON.parse(localStorage.markers) : {};
};

function addMarkerToLocalStorage(lat, lng, id) {
  var markers = getMarkersFromLocalStorage();
  markers[id] = {
    lat: lat, 
    lng: lng
  };
  localStorage.markers = JSON.stringify(markers);
};

function removeMarkerFromLocalStorage(id) {
  console.log('removeMarkerFromLocalStorage');
  var markers = getMarkersFromLocalStorage();
  delete markers[id];
  localStorage.markers = JSON.stringify(markers);
};

function renderMarkers() {
  var markers = getMarkersFromLocalStorage();  

  for(prop in markers) {
    generateMarker(markers[prop].lat, markers[prop].lng, prop);
  };
};

function generateMarker(lat, lng, id) {  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
    map: map
  }); 
  marker.id = id;
  addMarkerToLocalStorage(lat, lng, id);

  marker.addListener('rightclick', function(e) {
    var m = this;
    console.log(e, m['id']);    
    removeMarkerFromLocalStorage(m['id']);
    this.setMap(null);
  });   

};
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map">
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

It looks like local storage is not available in SO fiddle, you can check the code at https://jsfiddle.net/xomena/fyma08ov/

I hope this helps!